# limit $x$ tends to zero $(f(x^2) - f(x)) / (f(x)-f(0))$

Tags: limits

If $f$ is differentiable and a strictly increasing function, then what is the following?

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x^2) - f(x)}{f(x)-f(0)}$$

Thank you.

Comment: If $f'(0)\neq0$, then:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x^2) - f(x)}{f(x)-f(0)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x^2)-f(0)+f(0)-f(x)}{x} \cdot \frac{x-0}{f(x)-f(0)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(x \cdot \frac{f(x^2)-f(0)}{x^2-0}-\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right)\cdot \frac{x-0}{f(x)-f(0)} =(0 \cdot f'(0)-f'(0))\cdot \frac{1}{f'(0)}=-1.$$

Comment: This has been very helpful, thank you

Comment: It can happen that $f'(0)=0$ exists, but $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x^2) - f(x)}{f(x)-f(0)}$$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

You could even do a bit more if you practice Taylor series. Built at $x=0$, you have $$f(x)=f(0)+x f'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 f''(0)+\frac{1}{6} f'''(0) x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Doing the same (using the chain rule) $$f(x^2)=f(0)+x^2 f'(0)+O\left(x^4\right)$$ So, $$\frac{f(x^2) - f(x)}{f(x)-f(0)}=\frac{-x f'(0)+x^2 \left(f'(0)-\frac{f''(0)}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{6} f'''(0)
   x^3+O\left(x^4\right)}{x f'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 f''(0)+\frac{1}{6} f'''(0) x^3+O\left(x^4\right)}$$ Now, performing the long division (provided that $f'(0)\neq 0$) $$\frac{f(x^2) - f(x)}{f(x)-f(0)}=-1+x-\frac{ f''(0)}{2 f'(0)}x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$ which shows not only the limit but also how it is approached.

**Edit**

Using the same approach, you could show that, for any $n \geq 2$,  $$\frac{f(x^n) - f(x^{n-1})}{f(x^{n-1})-f(0)}=-1+x-\frac{ f''(0)}{2 f'(0)}x^n+\cdots$$

Comment: And what about the case $f'(0)=0$?

Comment: @GEdgar. Well, in such a case, it will be $-1+x^2$.

Comment: The limit is still $-1$.  And the next case, $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$, what then?  And finally, what if all derivatives are zero (but the function is still strictly increasing)?

Comment: These are good questions, indeed ! Do you see any way to answer in a general manner (say, all derivatives (up to $n$) are zero ? L'Hopital, probably. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, nice answer, but can be generalized to the case where $f(x)$ is not twice differentiable and we use the L^Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \arrow 0} \frac{f'(x^2)(2x)-f'(x)}{f'(x)-0}$ using L'hospital rule
$=\frac{f'(0)(0)-f'(0)}{f'(0)-0}$
$=\frac{-f'(0)}{f'(0)}=-1$